# Window (WPF). Не отображается список Events в окне Properties для Control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, usercontrol, controls

Я создаю проект WPF App(.Net Core). К примеру две кнопки. Если у одной кнопки задать любое событие, к примеру Click, то когда ее выбираешь в редакторе, в окне Properties не отображается список Events
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKR1j.png)

Если Event не установлен, то все нормально
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScrTW.png)

И так во всех проектах, с любыми Controls. Появилось это после обновления Visual Studio. Полностью переустанавливал Visual Studio 2019, ничего не помогает. Как это исправить? помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Руками научились писать и не в коем случае не трогайте редактор, XAML очень простой язык.

Comment: Баг студии? Репортите в поддержку, ну а вообще оно и не особо нужно, т.к. все это можно написать руками в xaml

Comment: Руками можно конечно, спору нет. Но окошко то удобное. Особенно со своими контролами, в которых уже не помнишь какие события выводил.. так нажимаешь на него, и с боку весь список..